# Null pointer in an intersecting method with arrays (java)

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, rectangles, intersect

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.Rectangle.intersects(Rectangle.java:786)
    at Robotron.intersecting(Robotron.java:182)
    at Robotron.run(Robotron.java:349)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The trouble is Here:

```
public void intersecting(Sprite r1, Sprite r2)
{
    System.out.println("The grunts isAlive is: "+r1.isAlive+" his xpos is: "+r1.rec.x+" his ypos is: "+r1.rec.y);
    if(r1.rec.intersects(r2.rec) && r1.isAlive==true && r2.isAlive==true)
    {
        r1.isAlive=false;
        r2.isAlive=false;
    }
}
```

The output of my System.out is: `The grunts isAlive is: true his xpos is: 936 his ypos is: 478`. But for some reason its giving me a null pointer

This is how I initialize my Grunts, Maybe the issue lies there?

```
for(int i=0; i<grunt.length;i++)
{
    int randX = (int)(Math.random()*worldx);
    int randY = (int)(Math.random()*worldy);
    if(hero.outerCircle.inCircle(randX,randY)!=true)
    {
        grunt[i] = new EnemyD4(randX,randY, worldx, worldy, 50,70);
    }
    if(hero.outerCircle.inCircle(randX,randY)==true)
    {
        randX+=100;
        grunt[i] = new EnemyD4(randX,randY, worldx, worldy, 50,70);
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you calling ```intersecting()```?

Comment: Where does the null pointer exception occurring at ?

Comment: one possible cause is because threads and the main program execute separately. But again, show us the full (commented) code to understand the problem.

Answer (score 3):

In cases like this just follow the stacktrace! I am guessing from it that the null pointer is thrown here:

```
if(r1.rec.intersects(r2.rec) && r1.isAlive==true && r2.isAlive==true)
```

To be exact it's thrown here `r1.rec.intersects(r2.rec)` (which assumes that `r1.rec` and `r2.rec` aren't null).

If you check the code for `Rectangle#intersects(Rectangle r)` in the awt package you will see that on line 786 you have:

```
int rw = r.width;
```

And that's where the NPE occurs. `r` here is your `r2.rec` which means that it's null. You either need to check for this case before calling `intersects()` or you need to fix how you are calling `intersecting(Sprite r1, Sprite r2)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your input to intersects is null. When you check your if condition, check r1 and r2 first:

```
if(r1.isAlive==true && r2.isAlive==true && r1.rec.intersects(r2.rec)) {
  ...
}
```